# java validation code to check wether the given input is either a number or word or a date?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a drop down and a text box beside that, if 2nd or 3rd element selected in drop down then the text box beside that drop down should accept only number or word or date,no special character is allowed. Can any one provide server side java code validation for this?

```
if(badRowDetails.getOperator()==2 || badRowDetails.getOperator ()==3)            
{
     char c[]=value.toCharArray ();
     int count=0;
     int count1=0;
     for(int i=0;i<value.length ();i++)
     {
         int ascii=(int)c[i];
         if((ascii >=97 && ascii<=122) || (ascii>=65 && ascii<=90))
         {   
             count=count+1;
         }
     }
     try
     {
        int num=Integer.parseInt(value);               
     }
     catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
     {                
         System.out.println ("Exception raised .  "+nfe.getMessage ());
         count1=count+1;
     }            
     if(count==0 && count1>0)
     {
         errors.reject ("value","Operator IS , ISN'T can only have words,Numbers.");
     }           

    }
}
```

thank you

Comment: you can use regex... For date i think you have to put a delimiter like / or - .

Comment: can you please write the code or can you show me the demo in jsfiddle

Comment: provide some use cases , 11, aab,aa11, and format of date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String... args) {

 String s = "12:12:1990";
 System.out.println(s.matches("(\\d+|\\w+|([0-2][0-9]|([3]([0]|[1]))):([0][1-9]|[1][1-2]):([1][9][0-9][0-9]|[2][0][0-9][0-9]))"));

}
```

PS : date has delimiter ":" (assumed) and ranges between (1900 and 2099). You can change it to whatever delimiter you want by replacing ":" with your delimiter in the code.  Doesnt handle LEAP YEAR condition...

```
IP:Hello OP : true 
IP :123 OP : true  
IP :12:12:2011  Op :true 
IP: 12:44:2012 OP :false
IP :][ OP :false
IP : 32:12:2013 OP : false
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex like the following will return true if the string is alphanumeric:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
  return true; 
} 
return false;
```

Date is tougher.  I'd lookup regex for validating date.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex as below:

```
    if(badRowDetails.getOperator()==2 || badRowDetails.getOperator ()==3)            
    {
        if(!value.matches("[A-Za-z0-9-]*")) {
            errors.reject ("value","Operator IS , ISN'T can only have words,Numbers.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Alpha Numeric, I would prefer to validate using regular expression, use `DateFormatter` to check a date (since it needs lot of validation such as  leap year, month,date, year etc)

Here you go quick example how I do it,
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String s1="111";
    String s11 ="11aa*";
    String s2="hello";
    String s3="2013-05-11";

    System.out.println("Is number 111  "+isAlphaNum(s1));
    System.out.println("Is number 11aa* "+isAlphaNum(s11));
    System.out.println("Is word hello "+isAlphaNum(s2));

    System.out.println("Is date 2013-05-11 "+isaDate(s3));
    System.out.println("Is date 111 "+isaDate(s1));
    System.out.println("Is date hello "+isaDate(s2));

}

private static boolean isAlphaNum(String word){
    return word.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
}

private static boolean isaDate(String text){
    if (text == null || !text.matches("\\d{4}-[01]\\d-[0-3]\\d")){
        return false;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    df.setLenient(false);
    try {
        df.parse(text);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You may change the date format globaly(dynamic) as you require

Comment: but its also allowing combination of any number of integers and hyphens (-) in any order,but it should not,,,,example: it should accept 12-12-2000 but not as 12-12-12-12 or 1231-123-333 or --- etc

Comment: you need to define the rules first